# Does an ADFS v2 server have to be on the actual domain server?

Tags: active-directory, adfs

Can an ADFS v2 server be installed stand-alone, or is it tightly coupled with the AD server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not recommended on a DC. It must be installed on a domain member server. No workgroup boxes allowed.